# VScode terminal creating react app folder directly on the drive instead of the commanded folder when running npx create-react-app appname

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

[image]

I'm new to VScode I installed react properly through terminal but when I try to run **npx create-react-app appname** VScode terminal creates react app folder directly on the drive instead of the commanded folder.

Comment: stay to folder D:\react-folder> cd first

Comment: then type npm start

Comment: folder 'first' is not inside react-folder! its getting created inside D: drive directly. react-folder is empty.

Comment: open cmd in the desired folder then type npx create-react-app  appname after process then type cd appname then code .

Comment: We suggest that you begin by typing:

  cd first
PS D:\react-folder> cd first
cd : Cannot find path 'D:\react-folder\first' because it does not exist.